# Airflow dag with past end_date doesn't trigger schedule

Tags: apache-spark, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have a airflow dag with the following configuration:

```
{
 'start_date': datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
 'end_date': datetime(2019, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  schedule_interval='@yearly',
  catchup=True
}
```

For the above, 2 schedules are created on

```
=> 2017-01-01, 2018-01-01.
```

It doesn't create for 2019-01-01, since I understand the scheduler schedules only after the schedule interval is completed. In this case 2019 is still not over, so it is not scheduled.

Since I have given the end_date, shouldn't the scheduler understand the end_date is over and trigger that.

I know the solution where by adjusting the start_date to one year back and adjusting the date ranges(execution_date + 1 year) within the job. (e.g. schedule it from start_date: 2016-01-01). So we will have 3 schedules (2016, 2017, 2018) to get all the windows.

Is there anyone way to handle this or am I missing something ?. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Alex